# C code: left shift is shifting but dropping top bits

Tags: c, shift

I'm doing a small embedded project where I have 40 bits transferred through a SPI type interface. I pull these bits off of a 32 bit bus and place the upper 32 bits into a `uint32_t` variable and the lower 8 bits into a `uint8_t` variable. I'm trying to combine them into a single `uint64_t`. However when I shift by 8, it drops the top 8 bits. Here is my code.

```
uint64_t getError()
{
    uint32_t * disp_addr = (uint32_t*)(MYDISPLAY);

    uint64_t error_upper;
    uint8_t error_lower;
    uint64_t error= 0;

    error_lower = *(disp_addr+1);
    error_upper = *(disp_addr+0);
    error = ((uint64_t) error_upper) <<8 | error_lower;
    return error;
}
```

This code is working except for the fact that it's dropping my top 8 bits.
Any thoughts or hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**edit**

```
uint64_t getError()
{
    uint32_t * disp_addr = (uint32_t*)(MYDISPLAY);

    uint64_t error_upper;
    uint8_t error_lower;
    uint64_t error= 0;

    error_lower = 0x34;
    error_upper = 0xABCDEF12;
    error = ((uint64_t) error_upper) <<8 | error_lower;
    printf("%010x", error);
    //return error;
}
```

Results:
00cdef1234

Comment: What would be the desired behavior?

Comment: Of course it is dropping.. Where would they go?

Comment: Cast the upper bits var before shifting.

Comment: It should concatenate error_upper and error_lower in the lower 40 bits of my uint64_t error. I get that if I left shift a 32 bit int the top bits would drop off. but if I typecast it as a 64 bit int and shift it, shouldn't it move those bits into positions 33-40?

Comment: @WeatherVane Cast to what?

Comment: my original code was error = ((uint64_t) error_upper<<8) | error_lower; but that didn't work either.

Comment: Maybe your hardware doesn't handle 64-bit values as a whole but splits them somehow and loses the bits?  Can you do a shift of **only** `error_upper` without the `| error_lower` and see if you still lose the top bits?

Comment: @EugeneSh. mybad - misread it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, that is an interesting idea. I've already tried doing a shift strictly on error_upper and it still drops the bits, which would suggest maybe my hardware doesn't support it.

Comment: I doubt it is a hardware issue. It would be helpful if you hardcode some values, run the code and show the results.

Comment: @SparkyGuru Please try to provide more information about which CPU and compiler that is used. The error cannot be reproduced with the code posted. I would suspect some compiler oddity on the given system, maybe a glitchy `uint64_t` handling mechanism on a 32 bit compiler.

Comment: As @Lundin, cannot reproduce. Were the bits there in the first place?

Comment: Btw the endianess of your SPI interface and/or display is not necessarily the same as the endianess of your CPU. SPI data is often in big endian format and MCUs may have any endianess. But I don't see how this would cause the mentioned issue.

Comment: Your printf format needs to be `%0llX`.

Comment: You are just not printing it right. use `%llx`

Comment: @WeatherVane right, I had a typo before, my printf format was %010x.

Comment: `printf("%010x", error);` is printing `00cedf1234`. `printf("%010llx", error);` is printing `abcedf1234`. I think we can close the question here..

Comment: Indeed... the printf functions are evil. Before posting questions like this, view your actual data in the debugger maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `printf` format specifier is incorrect.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned __int64 uint64_t;
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

int main(void) {
    uint64_t error_upper, error;
    uint8_t error_lower;

    error_lower = 0x34;
    error_upper = 0xABCEDF12;
    error = (error_upper << 8) | error_lower;
    printf("%x\n", error);
    printf("%llx\n", error);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
cedf1234
abcedf1234
```

Comment: when I try printf("%llx\n", error); I get 500000ffffffffff.

Comment: @WeatherVane `double L` is what I used.

Comment: @SparkyGuru if I run that exact code that's the output from the two formats. LPs deleted his recent comment, I deleted my reply.

Comment: `%x` requires an argument of type `unsigned int`; using it with a `uint64_t` argument has undefined behavior. `%llx` requires an argument of type `unsigned long long int`; using it with a `uint64_t` argument has undefined behavior *unless* `uint64_t` is defined as `unsigned long long int` (which it commonly is). `<inttypes.h>` defines macros for `printf` formats for the types defined in `<stdint.h>` -- or you can convert to `uintmax_t` and use `%ju`: `printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t)x);`

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks, I think your comment on expected arguments helped the most. I'm kind of a noob programmer. I'm an EE student thrown into a programming role.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you saying that the upper byte is cut?
If I use your code and print the result is ok:

```
uint32_t temp = 0x01020304;
uint32_t *disp_addr = &temp;
uint64_t error_upper;
uint8_t error_lower;
uint64_t error= 0;

error_lower = *(disp_addr+1);
error_upper = *(disp_addr+0);
error = (error_upper<<8) | error_lower;

printf("\n%08X%08X\n",  (uint32_t)(error>>32), error);
```

Output is

```
0000000102030401
```

Are you using `%d` to printout the value?

Comment: @SparkyGuru AFAIK %X evaluate 32 bits variables. Your code is correct is your fprintf the problem.

Comment: Possibly, I don't see why it would be. is there a way I can test that?

Answer (score -1):

Look carefully at

```
uint32_t *disp_addr = &temp;
...
error_lower = *(disp_addr+0);
```

Because `disp_addr` is a ptr to uint32_t you are storing a 32bit value in a 8bit variable. Depending on your machine endiannes and how you load `disp_addr` you may be loading the wrong data.

You probably wanted to do:

```
uint32_t *disp_addr = &temp;
...
error_lower = *(uint8_t *)(disp_addr+0);
```

which is not the same.

Comment: Good comment, buy definetly not an answer